# VS2013 Test Explorer alternative

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

For VS2013.
I'm looking for a *free* unit-test explorer that can show the unit-test class name as well.

The built-in test explorer missing this feature, or I can't figured out how to show it.

As my unit test codes growing, simply showing just the method name is not enough, as this will force me to create unique method names thoughout the whole solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Group by feature to categorize by class:

[image]

Note that you can also use the [`[Description("A better name for my test")]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.descriptionattribute.aspx) so you won't have to rely on the method name alone.

Comment: As for alternatives, Jetbrains Resharper, DevExpress CodeRush, Typemock isolator SmartRunner and Telerik JustCode offer replacements for the standard Visual Studio Test Runner. These are all paid solutions though.

Comment: Didn't noticed/aware of that feature. It will be more accessible if show in main window or right click context.